# How to enable/disable chatbot from Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, rasa

I have successfully built a chatbot rasa app to connect with Facebook Messenger. The bot is responsible for replying user's message instead of the admin page. I want something more flexible. Users can enable/disable chatbot. When users disabled chatbot they will chat with the admin page instead (The bot will not listen until it is turned on again)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to achieve something like if the user asks to talk to a human, then the bot hands off to the admin page?

Comment: @AkelaDrissner That's right, that's what I want. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

To pause the conversation with the bot, if the user asks to be handed off to a human, you can write a [rule](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/rules) that executes a custom action when that intent is triggered, which returns a [`ConversationPaused`](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/reference/rasa/shared/core/events#conversationpaused-objects) event. That way the bot stops listening to the user, and a person from your admin page can reply. There is a `ConversationResumed` event in that link which you can use to resume the conversation with the bot again.

Comment: I can pause a conversation with `ConversationPaused`, but I don't know how to use `ConversationResumed` to return the conversation. Actions are no longer active when I pause conversation. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: There's also a [blog post](https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-human-handoff-feature-with-rasa/) on this subject with example code that should be helpful.

Comment: @PhucNguyen, you will need to have an external API call perform the `ConversationResumed` event. I'm not 100% sure how that works through Facebook and if it's possible to do that with the press of a button from the human agent.